# Wrong profile is active

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SfgDiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SfgDiApplication.class, args);

        PetController petController = ctx.getBean("petController", PetController.class);
        System.out.println("--- The Best Pet is ---");
        System.out.println(petController.whichPetIsTheBest());
}


@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class PetController {

    public PetController(PetService petService) {
        this.petService = petService;
    }

    private final PetService petService;

    @GetMapping("pet-type")
    public String whichPetIsTheBest(){
        return petService.getPetType();
    }
}



public interface PetService {

    String getPetType();
}




@Service("cat")
public class CatPetService implements PetService {
    @Override
    public String getPetType() {
        return "Cats Are the Best!";
    }
}



@Profile({"dog", "default"})
public class DogPetService implements PetService {
    public String getPetType(){
        return "Dogs are the best!";
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dog
```

**Result**

```
--- The Best Pet is ---
Cats Are the Best!
```

I don't understand why cats are here.  I can even comment the properties out, but cats are still here. I would like to see dogs.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the DogService is not a bean. So in the end you only have a single bean (CatService) and this one will be picked all the time.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should define a **bean** of **DogPetService** with ***@service***.
2. You should add the cat **profile** to **CatPetService**.
   Like this :

   ```
   @Service("cat")
   @Profile({"cat"})
   public class CatPetService implements PetService {
   @Override
   public String getPetType() {
       return "Cats Are the Best!";
    }
   }

   @Profile({"dog", "default"})
   @Service("dog")
   public class DogPetService implements PetService {
       public String getPetType(){
           return "Dogs are the best!";
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want like this:

```
@Configuration("petConfig")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PetConfig {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String type;

    @Bean(name = "petService")
    @Primary
    public PetService petService() {

        PetService petService = null;
        if ("cat".equals(type)) {
            petService = new CatPetService();
        }
        if ("dog".equals(type)) {
            petService = new DogPetService();
        } 
        return petService;
    }
}
```

Annotate both CatPetService and DogPetService with @Service. This way you can easily adapt the code without hardcodings and duplication.